# How to activate an existing GVim window

Tags: vim

What I'm searching for is a command similar to:

```
gvim --remote-silent FILE
```

But without the `FILE` part. So basically: launch a new GVim instance if none exists, and otherwise activate/focus the existing window. I prefer not to use a dummy file (eg. `gvim --remote-silent ~/.vimrc`) as that would mess up my bufferlist/MRU.

The reason I'm looking for something like this, is that I'd like to configure a shortcut for GVim (`Mod+8`) to use in the Linux XFCE window manager.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can re-activate an existing GVIM instance with

```
$ gvim --remote-send ":call foreground()<CR>"
```

That fails when there's no existing server. In that case, just spawn a fresh instance, or check beforehand with `gvim --serverlist`.

Comment: Cool, this seems to work: `[ -z \`gvim --serverlist\` ] && gvim || gvim --remote-send ":sil call foreground()<CR>"`

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu `gvim --remote-silent` works but doesn't activate editor window and just waves its icon in sidebar. To change this behavior [look here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594294/how-to-automatically-bring-an-activated-window-to-the-foreground).

> This behaviour can be changed from the command line, open a terminal
>   and type:
>
> dconf write
>   /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/focus-prevention-level 0
>
> To restore the default value:
>
> dconf write
>   /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/focus-prevention-level 1

Comment: Can you provide a summary of the solution provided in the link as part of your answer? That way, the information is preserved even if the link becomes invalid.